# How to compare data using WHERE clause TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically, I want to see the difference in data based on a site code, for instance

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data.base.table
WHERE
    site = 1
    site = 2
```

Even though it's the same table, I want to compare differences based on that site code, but I can't figure out how.  My initial chain of thought was to use a left join, but there's only one table.

Thanks

Comment: Id `site = 1` one row and `site = 2` another one row?

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing differences"? What is the exact expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the differences by using [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188055(v=sql.110).aspx)

Try this:

```
SELECT
* --Your column list minus site
FROM
data.base.table
WHERE
site = 1
EXCEPT  
SELECT
*--Your column list minus site
FROM
data.base.table
WHERE
site = 2
```

Comment: this will return all rows since site will never be identical

Comment: Agreed - you would need to exclude site in the column list

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you may try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data.base.table
WHERE
    site in(1,2)
```

This will give the data having the site 1 and 2 and then you can compare the two rows